# How can I navigate to the screen before root?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to implement a cancel button that will do something like navigation.popTopop(). The problem is it navigates back to a screen before the one I expect it to be since that screen was the root of the whole navigation history. Is it possible to give it an index?

It's hard to set to a specific screen since screens are nested with tabs and it would be so much simpler to just go back couple of screens.

```
e.g.
navigation.navigate(SCREEN_A);
...
navigation.navigate(SCREEN_B);
...
navigation.navigate(SCREEN_C);
...
navigation.navigate(SCREEN_D);
```

I'm trying to go to SCREEN_B without explicitly set screen to SCREEN_B. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the `getId` function to identify screens:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen/#getid

```js
<Stack.Screen
  name={SCREEN_B}
  component={ScreenB}
  getId={({ params }) => params.someId}
/>
```

Now, if you navigate to `navigation.navigate(SCREEN_B, { someId: 'someId' })`, it's only going to navigate to the old screen if `someId` param is the same.

Alternatively if you always want to `push` a new screen, you can use `push`:

```js
navigation.push(SCREEN_B)
```